# Sub domain hiting Nginix index page and not the API

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment, subdomain

I have an Amazon EC2 box, and I am trying to host my node js REST API in the box. I run the application as a background process using PM2. To expose the locally running background application to the web, I create a Nginix web server. Now when I try to access the public DNS of the EC2 box, I can access the api like ec2-bla-bla.amazonaws.com/api and I can have it consumed by the front end applications.  All the communication is going on HTTP for right now.

But I cant let people use this DNS to consume my API as the DNS is owned by Amazon and not by us. So we created a separate sub domain called api.our-company.com and point it to EC2 public IP. But when I go to api.our-company.com, its displays the nginix index page, so that means its hitting the EC2 box. But when I call api.our-company.com/api, it gives me a nginix 404 error and wont let me access my api.

I need to be able to use api.our-company.com/api to consume my API.
I tried changing the root in my applications config file in sites-enabled. Tried removing index.html completely from the file. but it still displays the index page.  I am following this digital ocean article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Here is my project config file in sites-enabled.

```
upstream app_nodejs {
server 127.0.0.1:8080;
keepalive 8;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
listen 443 default ssl;

root /var/www/express-api/public/api;
index index.html index.html;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name api.our-company.com;

location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwar$
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

Here is the nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

I don't have much experience on hosting web servers. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem. It was not a configuration setting. It was just that the C Name of the sub-domain (api.our-company.com) was not pointing to Amazon's EC2 public DNS. We changed the C Name and now I can access my api from api.our-company.com/api .

Answer (score 0):

As you are using upstream, try passing

```
proxy_pass app_nodejs;
```

and

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
```

Use below references, as you are newbie to NGINX webserver

Reference:

1. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/
2. https://nginxconfig.io/

Comment: I tried using proxy_pass for the upstream and setting server default to 80. The 
 problem still persists. I already tried the sample server blocks. It doesn't deal with the problem.